# Summing data in row of certain attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, summarizing

In my shapefile, I have calculated some indicators for each polygon. Now I want to create a new field having sum of these indicators.

I created new field and populated it with desired values using expression in QGIS. But, the resulting column have some blank rows despite not all of the indicators being `NULL`. it is observed only for those rows, where any of the indicator is `NULL`. I have used this expression

[image]

and here are all the values:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Which field types do your other columns have?

Comment: All the fields are of type qlonglong and type name is  Integer64

Comment: Try `"crabs" + "schrimps"` instead of `crabs + schrimps`

Comment: "crabs" + "schrimps" instead of crabs + schrimps didn't work. Still getting NULL
And nullif is also not working

Comment: @Taras actually `nullif()` does the oposite: if `value1` equals `value2`, then the function returns `Null`, else it returns `value1`. In this case, if `crabs==0` then the function returns `Null`, else it return the value of `crab`... which remains `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function to replace a `null` by a value is [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#coalesce)

```
coalesce(crayfish,0) + coalesce(shrimp,0) + ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use the following expression the get the **sum of all fields** in your attribute table and where `NULL` is treated as `0` ([needs QGIS 3.18+](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays)):

```
array_sum (map_avals (attributes ( ) ))
```

If you do not want all fields to sum up, but **exclude some of the attributes**, use this expression and add a comma-delimited enumeration of the attribute-names you want to exclude (here: `fid, value`):

```
array_sum (array_filter (map_avals (attributes( ) ), @element not in (fid, value)))
```

*Screenshot, creating the sum of all attribute values **except** the last two ones (`fid` and `value`), where `NULL` is ignored:*
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Replace all NULL values with "0" - Open field calculator, set "Update Existing Field" and put in the expression (you need to repeat this for all columns):

`if("crayfish" is null, 0, "crayfish")`

Comment: This worked. But I have to do it for each indicator/ columns. I exported the attribute table in excel file and then created the desired column and created a new field in attribute table in QGIS. Using `Join`, I added the field to attribute table.

Comment: huh, this seems quite complicated. why did you export it to excel and then re-import it to QGIS?

Comment: Because in excel, all the 'NULL' values are treated as blank cell (0), so, now, I will get the correct sum. This process is a bit complicated, but since I need to create only 1 or 2 column which has sum, I did this. In QGIS, I had to convert each column's NULL to 0.